# xpath selecting text from link in <td> & text from <td>

Tags: ruby, xpath

I have the following code which works very well:

```
rows = diary_HTML.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr')
food_diary = rows.collect do |row|
  detail = {}
  [
    ["Food", 'td[1]/text()'],   
    ["Calories", 'td[2]/text()'],
    ["Carbs", 'td[3]/text()'],
    ["Fat", 'td[4]/text()'],
    ["Protein", 'td[5]/text()'],
    ["Cholest", 'td[6]/text()'],
  ].each do |name, xpath|
    detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip
  end
  detail
end
```

However the "Food" td does not only include text, but also a link from which I want to get the text.

I know I can use `'td[1]/a/text()'`to get the link text, but how do I do both?

`'td[1]/a/text()' or 'td[1]/text()'`

**EDITED  - Added Snippet.**

I am trying to include the `<tr class="meal_header">
      <td class="first alt">Breakfast</td>` on the first row, all lines with other regular tds on other rows whilst excluding td1 on the bottom row.

```
<tr class="meal_header">
  <td class="first alt">Breakfast</td>
  <td class="alt">Calories</td>
  <td class="alt">Carbs</td>
  <td class="alt">Fat</td>
  <td class="alt">Protein</td>
  <td class="alt">Sodium</td>
  <td class="alt">Sugar</td>
</tr>
<tr>  
<td class="first alt">            
  <a onclick="showEditFood(3992385560);" href="#">Hovis (Uk - White Bread (40g) Toasted With Flora Light Marg, 2 slice</a> </td>
  <td>262</td>   
  <td>36</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr class="bottom">
  <td class="first alt" style="z-index: 10">
    <a href="/food/add_to_diary?meal=0" class="add_food">Add Food</a>
    <div class="quick_tools">
    <a href="#quick_tools_0" class="toggle_diary_options">Quick Tools</a>
    <div id="quick_tools_0" class="quick_tools_options hidden">
    <ul>
      <li><a onclick="showLightbox(200, 250, '/food/quick_add?meal=0&amp;date=2013-04-15'); return false;">Quick add calories</a></li>
     <li><a href="/meal/new?meal=0">Remember meal</a></li>
     <li><a href="/food/copy_meal?date=2013-04-15&amp;from_date=2013-04-14&amp;meal=0&amp;username=nickwild1">Copy yesterday</a></li>  
     <li><a href="#recent_meals_0" class="toggle_diary_options">Copy from date</a></li>             
     <li><a href="#recent_meals_copy_to_0" class="toggle_diary_options">Copy to date</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
   <div id="recent_meals_0" class="recent_meal_options hidden">
    <ul id="recent_meal_options_0">
    <li class="header">Copy from which date?</li>        
    <li><a href="/food/copy_meal?date=2013-04-15&amp;from_date=2013-04-14&amp;meal=0&amp;username=nickwild1">Sunday, April 14</a></li>
    <li><a href="/food/copy_meal?date=2013-04-15&amp;from_date=2013-04-13&amp;meal=0&amp;username=nickwild1">Saturday, April 13</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>285</td>
  <td>39</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td></td>
```

Comment: Please provide example input.

Comment: If you can alter the Ruby - `row.at_xpath("td[1]").content()` . . .

Comment: @NeilSlater Yes can alter Ruby. Whereabouts should I change?

Comment: I think you can just alter your first regular expression to exclude the bottom row. E.g. `'//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[@class!="bottom"]'`, and then fetch it separately to extract tds 2 to 7 . . . there might be more elegant solutions too

Comment: @NeilSlater thanks, but this addition knocks out the main lines

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: use `Nokogiri::XML::Element#text`, it will give the text of the element plus subelements (your `a` for example).

You can also clean that code up quite a bit:

```
keys = ["Food", "Calories", "Carbs", "Fat", "Protein", "Cholest"]
food_diary = rows.collect do |row|
  Hash[keys.zip row.search('td').map(&:text)]
end
```

And as a final tip, avoid using xpath with html, css is so much nicer.

Comment: @pguardino THanks for this. I think I will have to do by css anyhow, but this is great elegant code!

Comment: #text is available on NodeSet and also Node. Let's agree to delete these comments ok?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this by altering the logic to look at element content when you don't have an explicit `text()` extraction in the xpath

```
rows = diary_HTML.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr')
food_diary = rows.collect do |row|
  detail = {}
  [
    ["Food", 'td[1]'],   
    ["Calories", 'td[2]/text()'],
    ["Carbs", 'td[3]/text()'],
    ["Fat", 'td[4]/text()'],
    ["Protein", 'td[5]/text()'],
    ["Cholest", 'td[6]/text()'],
  ].each do |name, xpath|
    if xpath.include?('/text()')
      detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip
    else
      detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).content.strip
    end
  end
  detail
end
```

You could also add e.g. a symbol to the array, to describe how you were extracting the data, and have a `case` block which handled items depending on what the last stage was to do following the `xpath`

Note you could also do what you want by walking the node structure returned by xpath recursively, but that seems like overkill if you just want to ignore markup, links etc.

Comment: Thanks Neil this is great, but it does bring up some other 'junk'in other tds that I don't want. Can this just be limited to "Food"?

Comment: In my example it should be deciding which element to extract .content or just plain .to_s from based on whether you have explicitly asked for '/text()' in the path. Is that not happening for you? I tested with `xml = "<tr><td>Hello <a>there</a> you</td><td>2 <b>Not this!</b></td><td>3</td><td>3</td><td>3</td><td>3</td></tr>"` and got `{"Food"=>"Hello there you", "Calories"=>"2", "Carbs"=>"3", "Fat"=>"3", "Protein"=>"3", "Cholest"=>"3"}` from my code

Comment: Sorry you're right it did work - just realised that I need to do by css as the other junk was in other rows of the "food" td

Comment: sorry one final question to save reworking in css (which I have not done before). Can I limit the `detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).content.strip` to only include items from another array `["breakfast", "Dinner", "Lunch"]`

Comment: @Nick Wild: I think that may be possible using xpath, but it would start to get complex, and maybe not your best choice for extracting the data you want. I'd also be guessing too much about your expected inputs and outputs at this stage, and I suggest you put more detail about them into this or a new question. A sample of input data would help a lot

Comment: Here is a link to the HTML file. The purpose of this is to include the meal names and food stats, but exclude "Add Food | Quick Tools" https://www.dropbox.com/s/98ezgjepi8busr7/nickwild1.html

Comment: Thanks. I meant you should put a relevant HTML snippet (not the whole file) into your question, so that anyone can help, and so that future people looking for similar answers can benefit.